# DataFrame: impute column with the median value of each category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset looks like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'sensor1': [1.94,0.93,0.98,1.75,1.75,3.25,0.5,0.5,5.59,6.02,9.21,4.54,3.71,1.05],
 'sensor2': [-0.91,0.42,-0.11,0.0,0.0,-0.12,0.0,0.0,0.48,0.26,-1.5,-0.75,-1.45,0.06],
 'sensor3': [18,19,20,-2094,-2094,17,17,17,-985,-985,1163,1163,1163,-1265],
 'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]}
)

df.head()
    sensor1 sensor2 sensor3 type
0   1.94    -0.91      18    1
1   0.93     0.42      19    1
2   0.98    -0.11      20    1
3   1.75     0.00   -2094    1
4   1.75     0.00   -2094    1
```

I negative value from output of `sensor3` means invalid. I would like to impute all invalid values in that column, using the `median` value of each `type` category.

**Required**

```py
    sensor1 sensor2 sensor3 type
0   1.94    -0.91     18     1
1   0.93     0.42     19     1
2   0.98    -0.11     20     1
3   1.75     0.00     19     1
4   1.75     0.00     19     1
5   3.25    -0.12     17     2
6   0.50     0.00     17     2
7   0.50     0.00     17     2
8   5.59     0.48     17     2
9   6.02     0.26     17     2
10  9.21    -1.50   1163     3
11  4.54    -0.75   1163     3
12  3.71    -1.45   1163     3
13  1.05     0.06   1163     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create mask for identify invalid values, here less like `0` by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html), then filter rows with inverted mask and aggregate `median`, last filter rows in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and mapping by medians by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
m = df['sensor3'].lt(0)

df.loc[m, 'sensor3'] = df.loc[m, 'type'].map(df[~m].groupby('type')['sensor3'].median())
print (df)
    sensor1  sensor2  sensor3  type
0      1.94    -0.91       18     1
1      0.93     0.42       19     1
2      0.98    -0.11       20     1
3      1.75     0.00       19     1
4      1.75     0.00       19     1
5      3.25    -0.12       17     2
6      0.50     0.00       17     2
7      0.50     0.00       17     2
8      5.59     0.48       17     2
9      6.02     0.26       17     2
10     9.21    -1.50     1163     3
11     4.54    -0.75     1163     3
12     3.71    -1.45     1163     3
13     1.05     0.06     1163     3
```

Comment: What an elegant solution. Thanks!